# Xubuntu is not showing the application icon at top left corner

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, icons, xfce

Installed Xubuntu 22.04 in my laptop which is xfce desktop environment.

I noticed that the application icon on top left corner of each window is not showing.

Though as per the screenshots from [xfce website](https://xfce.org/) its available.

In my case:
[image]

Can anyone give some clue to fix this or change some settings?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings -> Window manager -> Style`. In the title bar configuration, drag the "menu" square to the left part of the bar:

[image]

Comment: It was enabled in my case. When I changed the theme it started showing the icon.